# Memorizar input text de login

Tags: javascript, html5, cookies

Pessoal estou precisando gravar 2 campos da tela de login de meu programa, quero dar facilidade para o amigo que se logou, ele não precisar de digitar coisas como código da empresa, e email. Tentei utilizar o autocomplete porém não teve funcionalidade alguma. Existe alguma linguagem (HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT) que faça isto facil ou tenho que criar um método ?

Pensei em salvar em um cookies, onde se tiver ele salva se não ele não salva ?

Tentei fazer setando o autocomplete com jquery desta forma:

```
<script>
  jQuery('#codigo').attr('autocomplete','on');
  jQuery('#email').attr('autocomplete','on');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

SALVA EM SESSION É MAIS SEGURO!

```
$_SESSION["LOGIN"] = "VALOR";
```

Lembre-se: SESSION vai ficar salvo somente na sessão atual, fechando navegador a sessão vai apagar.

Não esqueça de ligar a session no topo do script:

Código:

```
session_start();
```

Se preferir salvar em cookie por um determinado tempo também é  ideal!

Comment: O problema da sessão é justamente o que você informou, preciso de algo que fica-se gravado, e achei o localstorage, ja havia utilizado ele em minhas aplicações mobile, porém me esqueci de seu potencial, mais obrigado pela sugestão !

Comment: Eu uso cookie e sessão. O usuário que escolhe na hora de fazer login marcando uma caixinha: "Lembra-me", ai salva em um cookie, caso ao contrario salva em session.

Answer (score 1):

A solução que achei foi muito mais simples do que pensei ser, eu utilizei a tecnologia de localstorage, ai pude salvar todos os dados necessarios para meu login.

```
        <script>
        var codigo = localStorage.getItem("codigo"),
                email = localStorage.getItem("email"),
                senha = localStorage.getItem("palavra");

        $("#codigo").val(codigo);
        $("#email").val(email);
        $("#palavra").val(senha);

        $("#entrar").click(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("codigo", $("#codigo").val());
            localStorage.setItem("email", $("#email").val());
            localStorage.setItem("palavra", $("#palavra").val());
        });

    </script>
```